# Triggering a scheduled task using process ID (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, task-scheduler, event-viewer, security-policy

How can I trigger a task in the Task Scheduler using a process ID that I get from the Task Manager? Sort of similiar to the event ID from the Event Viewer.

My first solution was to use the event ID indicating the process creation by enabling "Audit Process Tracking" but it keeps resetting to "No auditing" after every restart.

As second solution I tried to only enable "Audit Process Creation" and "Audit Process Termination" under Advanced Audit Policy Configuration. This solved the resetting problem but had the same issue as the first solution: After every restart or long inactivity, all of my app login info (Discord, Slack, different websites on OperaGX...) kept being deleted. History and autofill form data were there but I had to log in after every restart.

I would appreciate any solution that would allow me to trigger the scheduled task without resorting to the event ID from the event viewer or running scripts in the background. I'd be also glad if there's a way to prevent the Audit setting from forcing me to log in everytime on every app (which is just bizarre) which then I can use.

Thank you for your time in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Task Scheduler does not do what you want.

[Task scheduler conditions](https://wiki.idera.com/display/SQLejm/Defining+Conditions+for+your+Task)

> Idle Conditions Use this option when you want to run the task after
> the trigger is activated, only if the computer is in an idle state for
> a specific amount of time. You can specify the following settings:
> Start the task only if the computer is idle for ..... Stop if the
> computer ceases to be idle ...
>
> Power Conditions Use these options to run the task when your computer
> is on AC power only and to stop the task when it switches to battery
> power. Select any of the following options: Start the task only if the
> computer is on AC power ... Stop if the computer switches to battery
> power ... Wake the computer to run this task ....
>
> Network Conditions Use this option to start the task when Any
> connection ...

I have numerous Tasks here (most of which came with Windows) and none of them allow for using a Process ID

Comment: Thanks, but I already have 2 tasks that are triggered by a specific event.
https://ibb.co/VpCVBgy
The only reason I can't use it though, is because I have to enable Audit Process Tracking which resets my login info.

Comment: I think that is very specialized in its use.  The normal conditions are as I posted.